# ML .Net Can’t retrain the neural network

Tags: .net, ml.net

I am trying to retrain the model based on new data.
The neural network learning algorithm allows retraining according to the documentation.
[image]

```
//формируем данные для обучения из коллекции
var trainingDataView = 
mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainDataFromDb.TrainData);

//формируем данные в формате для обучения
var trainingPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "IdCategory", outputColumnName: "Label")
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "DescriptionProduct", outputColumnName: "DescriptionProductFeaturized"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "DescriptionProductFeaturized"))
    .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy())
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

//обучаем нейросеть
ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);

//используем FileStream
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FullPathModelNeural, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    //сохраняем обученную модель нейронной сети
    mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, trainingDataView.Schema, fileStream);
}
```

The neural network copes with the tasks assigned to it.

But as soon as I want to retrain it, I use the following code:

```
//загружаем обученную модель
var trainedModelFromFile = mlContext.Model.Load(FullPathModelNeural, out var modelSchema);

//извлекаем параметры обученной модели
var originalModelParameters = ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>)trainedModelFromFile).Model as MaximumEntropyModelParameters;

//формируем данные для обучения из коллекции
var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainDataFromDb.TrainData);

//дообучаем модель с учетом новых данных
var retrainedModel = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy().Fit(trainingDataView, originalModelParameters);

//используем FileStream
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FullPathModelNeural, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    //сохраняем обученную модель нейронной сети
    mlContext.Model.Save(retrainedModel, modelSchema, fileStream);
}
```

I get an exception. Failed to cast object type Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain [Microsoft.ML.ITransformer] to type Microsoft.ML.ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer [System.Object]
In this line of code

```
var originalModelParameters = ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>)trainedModelFromFile).Model as MaximumEntropyModelParameters;
```

Please, help me understand how to retrain the neural network correctly

Comment: Dear user, this is a free forum. We do not like commands here like "Help me...". It should at least be "Please help me" or something even more polite. Thanks

Comment: And please have a deep look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in how you saved your model, i.e. you saved more than just the Estimator.

A similar example that may help:

```
IDataView inputDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ModelInput>("initialdata.csv");

// Prepare input data to a form consumable by a machine learning model
var inputDataPreparer = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", nameof(ModelInput.Comment)).Fit(inputDataView); 

// Create a training algorithm 
var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LbfgsLogisticRegression();

var transformedData = inputDataPreparer.Transform(inputDataSplit.TrainSet);
var trainedModel = trainer.Fit(transformedData);

//Save the model
mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, inputDataView.Schema, "modelfile.zip");

//Save the input data preparing pipeline");
mlContext.Model.Save(inputDataPreparer, inputDataView.Schema, "preparePipeline.zip");


// -- Later retraining step --

// Load data preparation pipeline
ITransformer dataPrepPipeline = mlContext.Model.Load("preparePipeline.zip", out _);

// Load trained model
ITransformer originalModel = mlContext.Model.Load("modelfile.zip", out _);

// Extract trained model parameters
var originalModelParameters = ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<CalibratedModelParametersBase<LinearBinaryModelParameters, PlattCalibrator>>)originalModel).Model.SubModel; 

IDataView retrainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ModelInput>("MOREDATA.CSV");

var newData = dataPrepPipeline.Transform(retrainingDataView);
IDataView transformedNewData = dataPrepPipeline.Transform(newData);

// Retrain model
var retrainedModel = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LbfgsLogisticRegression().Fit(transformedNewData, originalModelParameters);

//Save complete pipeline for usage
var completeRetrainedPipeline = dataPrepPipeline.Append(retrainedModel);
mlContext.Model.Save(completeRetrainedPipeline, transformedNewData.Schema, "retrainedModel.zip);
```